# Is there a way to turn off the quiet mode in DCC32 called by MSBuild?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, dcc32

By default, the DCC32 compiler is called with the -Q switch that turns the quiet mode on. Is there a way to disable this switch in the .dproj file or by a command line parameter?

I use msbuild for the build automation in my Delphi project. Unfortunately I can't find any reference to the DCC32 parameters when it is executed by MSBuild. Usually I first change a compiler parameter in the Delphi IDE and then check what was changed in the project file. However, this approach won't work for the quiet mode as I can't find this option in the IDE.

Comment: It's probably in the msbuild target file which I think is found under the installation directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit your `$(BDS)\bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets` (XML) file and change the value of the `Quiet` attribute of the `DCC` node to `false`:

```
<DCC DelphiCompile="$(_ProjectFiles)"
...
      Quiet="false"
...
/>
```

Update: The DCC MSBuild task is configured to suppress the verbose dcc32 output. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33037590/11480) on how to change it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to take a copy of the targets file and pass that explicitly to msbuild? However that might be done. Modifying files in install dir is dubious surely.