# Blank lines instead of a task console output in MSBuild

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe3, dcc32

My product is being migrated from Delphi 6 to the newer Delphi XE3. The Delphi 6 compiler used to output list of files that were compiled to an executable:

```
Borland Delphi Version 14.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2002 Borland Software Corporation

ProjectName.dpr(X) 
...
PathToSomeUnit.pas(X) 
...
PathToSomeIncludedFile.inc(X)     
...
X lines, X.XX seconds, X bytes code, X bytes data.
```

where "X" mean some numbers

We have an internal software for analyzing dependencies between applications and particular files - units and included files. This software uses the dcc32 console output (like this one above) as its input.

With the new Delphi XE3 we no longer call dcc32 directly, but we use MSBuild. Unfortunately, the console output is not the same as with Delphi 6. When the "Quiet compile" option is disabled, the console output has multiple blank lines in place of the compiled file list.

```
Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 24.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2012 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.

[multiple blank lines]

X lines, X.X seconds, X bytes code, X bytes data. (TaskId:65)
```

With the /verbosity:diagnostic parameter it looks as follows

```
Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 24.0 (TaskId:65)
Copyright (c) 1983,2012 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. (TaskId:65)
(TaskId:65)
(TaskId:65)
(TaskId:65)
(TaskId:65)
(TaskId:65)
(TaskId:65)
...
X lines, X.X seconds, X bytes code, X bytes data. (TaskId:65)
```

When calling dcc32 directly, there was a similar problem, but it was resolved with the "-B" compiler switch (-B = Build all units).
I tried a similar approach with MSBuild by adding /p:DCC_AdditionalSwitches=-B but still it outputs multiple blank lines.

Comment: Read the information from the map file

Comment: Debug maps contain file names only, not full or relative paths. Is there a way to output paths id debug maps? The path is required for our software.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

1. Back up your files, etc.
2. Open a .NET Framework SDK v2.0 command prompt.
3. Disassemble `Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.dll` (located in your `$(BDS)\bin` directory):

   `ildasm Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.dll /out=Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.il`
4. Edit `Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.dcctask.xml` (created by the previous step) and comment out the `Ignore` subnode of the `OutputParsing` node.
5. Reassemble it:

   `ilasm Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.il /dll`
6. Register a strong name exception for it:

   `sn -Vr Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.dll`

If you turned off the quiet mode as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32992032/11480), building your Delphi projects with MSBuild should now show the detailed compiler output.

Answer (score 2):

Add **--depends** to DCC32 command line or **/p:DCC_OutputDependencies=true**
 to msbuild, it will output a **.d** file that can be easily parsed, like the example below:

```
C:\publico\BUILD\temp\YourDPR.exe: YourDPR.dpr \
        C:\blabla blabla\FrameWork\Base\biblioteca\dcus\unit15.dcu \
        C:\blabla blabla\FrameWork\Base\biblioteca\dcus\unit13.dcu \
        C:\bla bla\bla\LIBD5\Units\unit12.dcu \
        C:\blabla blabla\FrameWork\Base\biblioteca\rxlib\units\unit1.dcu \
        C:\blabla blabla\FrameWork\Base\biblioteca\rxlib\units\unit13.dcu \
        C:\bla bla\bla\LIBD5\Units\unit1.dcu \
        C:\bla bla\bla\LIBD5\Units\unit12.dcu \
```

Ps. You can hide those blank msbuild lines with **/p:DCC_Hints=false;**